# Open tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

For mysql, I have the following tables:

```
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 110M (Tables: 254)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 32M (Tables: 134)
[--] Data in MEMORY tables: 0B (Tables: 3)
```

but

```
[!!] Table cache hit rate: 19% (400 open / 2K opened)
```

I put 400 as the table cache because I have less than 400 tables.  How does this work and what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [MySQL page on Open and Closed Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html)

> MySQL is multi-threaded, so there may
> be many clients issuing queries for a
> given table simultaneously. To
> minimize the problem with multiple
> client sessions having different
> states on the same table, the table is
> opened independently by each
> concurrent session.
>
> **table_cache is related to
> max_connections.** For example, for 200
> concurrent running connections, you
> should have a table cache size of at
> least 200 × N, where N is the maximum
> number of tables per join in any of
> the queries which you execute. You
> must also reserve some extra file
> descriptors for temporary tables and
> files.
>
> **You can determine whether your table
> cache is too small by checking the
> mysqld status variable Opened_tables,
> which indicates the number of
> table-opening operations since the
> server started:**

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Opened_tables';
```

> If the value is very large or
> increases rapidly, even when you have
> not issued many FLUSH TABLES
> statements, you should increase the
> table cache size.